# Marble Trackman Scroll with holding Button only on Windows

Tags: windows, scroll, logitech, trackball

I bought a Logitech Marble Trackman. I am used to hold one button and roll the ball to scroll under linux. Now I am working under Win8 and installed Logitech SetPoint.
Now I have Universal Scroll and AutoScroll as options and both lock the scroll function. I need a second click to deactivate scrolling.

Is there a way to scroll only with button 4 hold?

Comment: Bump: No idea or no solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution after a long search.
It's this simple:

- throw away LogiTech SetPoint
- Install e.g. X-Mouse Button Control from http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm
- Configure everything you want.

Poor Logitech.